# How do show more activities on + create new record in dynamics global ribbon

Tags: crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365

In Dynamics 365 CE, The + Sign next left to advance find is showing only few activities, I need all activities shown there, what is the right way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

The global quick create button is enabled for entities which has quick create enabled and has a quick create form and also included in the model driven app.

Also the current user role has create privilege.

So if the activity satisfies these conditions should appear in the list.

However, for activities since these are special entities there could be some restrictions in creating certain type of activities. If the above steps doesnt make it appear in the list then that specific activity is special type which cant be created via global quick create.

Comment: Thank you. It worked for me. Quick create was missing on the entity. Created the form and clicked allow create on the entity.